# How to get the index value of FlatList in the header using React-native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I need to get the index value of the FlatList used in header of a React native component.

Below is the code I used.I need the parameter rowItem in onPressAction function which is returned as undefined

```
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
    this.state = {
        selectedItem: '',
        headerData: [
            { image: require('common/assets/images/headers/homeicon.png') },
            { image: require('common/assets/images/headers/CustomerDetails2.png') }
        ]
    }
}



componentDidMount() {
     // Event Listener for orientation changes
    Dimensions.addEventListener('change', () => {
        this.setState({
            orientation: isPortrait() ? 'portrait' : 'landscape'
        });
    });
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
        headerData: this.state.headerData,
        selectedItem: this.state.selectedItem,
        onPressAction: (item) => this.onPressAction()
    });
}
onPressAction = (rowItem) => {
    alert(rowItem);

}

static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
        headerTransparent: true,
        headerLeft: (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }} >
              <FlatList
                    horizontal={true}
                    extraData={navigation.getParam('selectedItem')}
                    data={navigation.getParam('headerData')}
                    renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={navigation.getParam('onPressAction')} >
                            <Image style={styles.centerIcon} resizeMode='contain' source={item.image}></Image>
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                    )}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                />

            </View >
        ),
        headerTintColor: 'transparent',
    };
};
```

Could anyone please help me

Answer (score 0):

Insert ID into `headerData` and use it as `index` value.

```js
        headerData: [
            { id: 0 , image: require('common/assets/images/headers/homeicon.png') },
            { id: 1 , image: require('common/assets/images/headers/CustomerDetails2.png') }
        ]
...

}
                    renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => alert(navigation.getParam('onPressAction'))} >
                            <Image style={styles.centerIcon} resizeMode='contain' source={item.image}></Image>
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                    )}
```

Comment: @CodeWriter  I modified my answer